# The order of functions execution (multithreading)

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using Java.

I have a main function and function f(). Thread is created in f(), but it takes more time that other operations in f(). What is the true order of the сapital letters?

```
main() {
  operations A;
  f();
  operations B;
}

f() {
  C;
  final Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          many operations, more than B+D;
          E;
        }
  };
  thread.start();
  D;
}
```

How would I make sure that order is A-C-D-B-E?

Comment: Spot the homework/assignment question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a condition variable to ensure some code won't run before notified. Assuming the whole procedure is run only once,

```
volatile boolean canGoOn = false;
final Object condition = new Object();

// in main:
B;
synchronized (condition) {
    canGoOn = true;
    condition.notify();
}

// in thread:
synchronized (condition) {
    while (!canGoOn) {
        condition.wait();
    }
}
E;
```

(Not tested, you may need to catch some InterruptedException.)

---

BTW If you are using Android this whole idiom is packaged into the [android.os.ConditionVariable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ConditionVariable.html) class, which you just need to `.open()` it in main and `.block()` it in thread.

Comment: You will need to use `synchronized(condition)` around `wait`/`notify` calls.

Comment: Also, it's good practice to make synchronization objects `final` as well and possibly declare `canGoOn` as `volatile`, but these are nitpicks.

Comment: @Tudor since you only access the condition variable inside a synchronized block you don't have to make it volatile.

Comment: @Voo: Agreed. I like to keep the `volatile` there to remind myself that it's a variable used between multiple threads.